# Code line wrapping - how to handle long lines

Tags: java, coding-style, conventions, line-breaks

I'm facing a particular line that is 153 characters long. Now, I tend to break things after 120 characters (of course, this is heavily dependent on where I am and the local conventions.) But to be honest, everywhere I break the line just makes it look bad. So I'm looking for some ideas on what I should do for it.

Here's the line:

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends Persistent>, PersistentHelper> class2helper = new HashMap<Class<? extends Persistent>, PersistentHelper>();
```

I'm open to both ideas about how/where to break the line (and why), as well as ways to shorten the line itself.

We're not a Java shop, and there aren't local conventions for this sort of thing, or obviously I would simply follow them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In general, I break lines *before* operators, and indent the subsequent lines:

```
Map<long parameterization> longMap
    = new HashMap<ditto>();

String longString = "some long text"
                  + " some more long text";
```

To me, the leading operator clearly conveys that "this line was continued from something else, it doesn't stand on its own." Other people, of course, have different preferences.

Comment: And as a related comment: wouldn't it be nice if Java had typedef?

Comment: Yes, yes it would. I'd even settle for &macros

Comment: I agree with the break before operators except with the assignment operator, I find it harder to read when your `=` is on the second line.  And soon Java will have the Diamond operator :)

Comment: I guess when I consider the two, I prefer it before even for `=`. I suppose that's just a matter of taste, but when I look at it, it makes the most sense.

Answer (score 28):

This is how I do it, and [Google](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.5-line-wrapping) does it my way.

- Break **before** the symbol for *non-assignment* operators.
- Break **after** the symbol for `=` and for `,`.

In your case, since you're using 120 characters, you can break it after the assignment operator resulting in

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends Persistent>, PersistentHelper> class2helper =
        new HashMap<Class<? extends Persistent>, PersistentHelper>();
```

In Java, and for this particular case, I would give two tabs (or eight spaces) after the break, depending on whether tabs or spaces are used for indentation.

This is of course a personal preference and if your project has its own convention for line-wrapping then that is what you should follow whether you like it or not.

Answer (score 7):

IMHO this is the best way to write your line :

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends Persistent>, PersistentHelper> class2helper =
        new HashMap<Class<? extends Persistent>, PersistentHelper>();
```

This way the increased indentation without any braces can help you to see that the code was just splited because the line was too long. And instead of 4 spaces, 8 will make it clearer.

Comment: A line can start with an operator but should never end with it, in this case `=`. Check auto-formatting in your IDE. NetBeans would change this code for sure (tested).

Comment: The defaults settings of an IDE aren't relevant to personal preferences or the recommendations of a developer.

I understand that some people would prefer to use the `=` at the beginning of the line, but in the case of the declaration of class attributes (or attributes in general for that matter) I consider that the code is already clear enough (the indentation of the second line should make it even more clear).

Comment: Just to be clear, there is no right and wrong here, it's purely aesthetics and personal opinions.

Comment: I would prefer to follow the same rule for all operators if possible, and when you think of operators like `+`, `-` and so on, it is obviously more readable to break a line before them - just as if you were summing up values on a piece of paper. I believe that is the reason why this approach is commonly used. I mentioned NetBeans IDE as an example, not as an oracle (the pun was not intended). I agree that everyone may have their own preference, yet it is commonsensical that one should be preferred, and I believe this is why we are talking about it to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

Uses Guava's static factory methods for Maps and is only 105 characters long.

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends Persistent>, PersistentHelper> class2helper = Maps.newHashMap();
```

Comment: +1 Very good idea. If you don't want the additional dependency, it is very easy to write such a static factory on your own.

Comment: I don't think using a library to get shorter lines is a good idea.

Comment: I would not recommend including it for that purpose, but many projects already use it. And as Helper Method pointed out, it's a one liner which saves some key strokes.

Comment: An interesting idea, obviously that method was introduced for exactly this problem.

Comment: You shouldn't use Google Guava Libraries just for the static factory methods. You should be using Guava because it will genuinely contribute to your java code quality in tons of other aspects. (Not to mention that it's wicked bullet proof due to the amount of time Google has spent on it...)

Answer (score 2):

I think that moving last operator to the beginning of the next line is a good practice. That way you know right away the purpose of the second line, even it doesn't start with an operator. I also recommend 2 indentation spaces (2 tabs) for a previously broken tab, to differ it from the normal indentation. That is immediately visible as continuing previous line. Therefore I suggest this:

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends Persistent>, PersistentHelper> class2helper 
            = new HashMap<Class<? extends Persistent>, PersistentHelper>();
```